# Error: Compile Error: Loop must iterate over a collection type: String at line 53 column 26

Tags: apex, class

```
public class Admin
{
public String Name{set;get;}
public Date Expiry{set;get;}
public Decimal InStock{set;get;}
public Date ManufacturingDate{set;get;}

public PageReference inserthere()
{
Insert_Drug__c ins=new Insert_Drug__c();
ins.Name=Name;
ins.Expiry_Date__c=Expiry;
ins.In_Stock__c=InStock;
ins.Manufacturing_Date__c=ManufacturingDate;
insert ins;
PageReference pg =new PageReference('https://c.ap2.visual.force.com/apex/Admin?success=true');
pg.setRedirect(true);
return pg;
}

public String DoctorName{set;get;}
public String DoctorUsername{set;get;}
public String DocPassword{set;get;}
public Decimal Doc_Age{set;get;}
public String Doc_Qualification{set;get;}
public String Doc_Speciality{set;get;}
public String Doc_Experience{set;get;}
public String Doc_Email{set;get;}
public String Doc_Contact{set;get;}

public PageReference insertdoc()
{
Doctor_Login__c doc=new Doctor_Login__c();
doc.Name=DoctorName;
doc.Age__c=Doc_Age;
doc.Contact__c=Doc_Contact;
doc.Email__c=Doc_Email;
doc.Experience__c=Doc_Experience;
doc.Password__c=DocPassword;
doc.Qualification__c=Doc_Qualification;
doc.Username__c=DoctorUsername; 
insert doc;
PageReference pg =new PageReference('https://c.ap2.visual.force.com/apex/home?success=true');
pg.setRedirect(true);
return pg;
}
public List<SelectOption> getitems() 
{
Doctor_Login__c obj =new Doctor_Login__c();
obj.Speciality1__c=Doc_Speciality;
obj=[select id,Speciality1__c from Doctor_Login__c where Speciality1__c=:Doc_Speciality limit 22];
List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
for(Doctor_Login__c se : obj.Speciality1__c)
{
options.add(new SelectOption('Doctor_Login__c',obj.Speciality1__c));
}
        return options;

        }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you at least called out where line 53 was and if you gave a bit of context.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is telling you the line and the problem (that the right-hand term needs to be a collection i.e. a list or array or set):

```
for(Doctor_Login__c se : obj.Speciality1__c)
```

Code like this (as `Speciality1__c` appears to be a text field) should fix:

```
public List<SelectOption> getitems() 
{
    List<AggregateResult> ars = [
            select Speciality1__c s
            from Doctor_Login__c
            group by Speciality1__c
            order by Speciality1__c
            ];
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    for(AggregateResult ar : ars)
    {
        String s = (String) ar.get('s');
        options.add(new SelectOption(s, s));
    }
    return options;
}
```

This assumes that the aim is to offer a picklist of any value that is already in the `Speciality1__c` field of the `Doctor_Login__c` object which may or may not be what you are looking for.